# Add spacing between stacks in Bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```css
.block {
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 5px auto;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
 }
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

It looks fine when I look in the large screen, but when I resize the window and they are stacked, then the two grey blocks will become one larger rectangular grey block. So how could I place spacing between them?

Comment: just add `margin` to space them

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0jv2x54b/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add `margin` to get this fixed..

**css**

```
.block{
    margin:5px auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but my case is a bit more complicated that the display is in table-cell and the margin does not seem to work.

Comment: @harrison Apply the margins to the `col-*` elements. http://www.bootply.com/P1YUIbGoXh